# Using variables from an HTML file with an external JS file

Tags: javascript, html, file

I am using Google Scripts to make a web-app that creates a spreadsheet based on data entered on the page.

Here's some example code:

page.html

```
<form id="form1">
Time 1:<br>
<input type="number" id="time1" name="time1"/>
</form>

<script>
var num = document.getElementById("time1").value;
google.script.run.test(num);
</script>
```

Code.gs

```
function test(thing) {
  return thing;
}
```

This would return undefined if I were to set an HTML element equal to the test function. How can I use the num variable from the HTML file with methods inside of my Code.gs file? I've looked through the Google APIs but there wasn't a solution that popped out at me, and I tried a couple things mentioned here on StackOverflow that didn't do the trick.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have to include the script in your document by linking it. Set the src attribute to the file path.

Comment: I did that, but I was still unable to use test(num) effectively.